Running Wdio on Jenkins throwing: npx: command not found
I am trying to run my Webdriver.io scripts locally using Jenkins. But somehow it is throwing error " npx: command not found" or "npm:npx: command not found" when i Run the build.
When i try to run the scripts locally using Terminal/Command Prompt, it works like a charm. But on Jenkins it is throwing error.
I am using ""@wdio/cli": "^8.32.3", and my Node version is:20.13.1. Below is the Console output log for the execution:
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/prabhavjoshi/.jenkins/workspace/Wdio-Test
[Wdio-Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/wc/lsq3g3w11nv_bhdmgcm33psh0000gq/T/jenkins86922904757060180.sh
+ cd /Users/prabhavjoshi/Documents/Automation/VPM_Automation/Git_new/ds_branch/tpl-wdio-vpm
[Wdio-Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/wc/lsq3g3w11nv_bhdmgcm33psh0000gq/T/jenkins7905346280461891349.sh
+ source /Users/prabhavjoshi/.zshrc
++ export PATH=/usr/local/opt/node@20/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
++ PATH=/usr/local/opt/node@20/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ node -v
v20.13.1
+ npm install

up to date, audited 788 packages in 2s

97 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
+ npm -v
10.5.2
+ npm i @wdio/cli

up to date, audited 788 packages in 4s

97 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
[Wdio-Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/wc/lsq3g3w11nv_bhdmgcm33psh0000gq/T/jenkins1234403545826098488.sh
+ npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --suite Login
/var/folders/wc/lsq3g3w11nv_bhdmgcm33psh0000gq/T/jenkins1234403545826098488.sh: line 2: npx: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I am expecting to pass my script with BUILD SUCCESS.
